# Fetch posts from postId firebase & swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I want to fetch the specific posts by they're `postId`. Is this something that is possible to do with firebase and swift?

Currently I'm getting a key from geofire which has all the postId keys that I want in it. Is it possible to get the post data relating to these `postIds` Here is my current attempt. My current attempt doesn't append any of the posts to my `collectionView`

```
var posts = [Post]()
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    let currentUserLocation = userLocation

    let circleQuery = geoFire?.query(at: currentUserLocation, withRadius: 100.0)

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    _ = circleQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in
        print(key)

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
        var postId = key

        ref.child(uid).child(postId).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.collectionView?.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

            guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in

                guard let dictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }

                guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid as? User else { return }

                var post = Post(user: user, dictionary: dictionary)
                post.id = key

                self.posts.append(post)
                self.posts.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
                return post1.creationDate.compare(post2.creationDate) == .orderedDescending
                })
            })
        }, withCancel: { (error) in
            print("There was an error getting the posts:", error)
        })

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    })
}
```

[image: Firebase database]

Comment: Please show your db structure

Comment: @elbertrivas added it to my question

Comment: Remove forEach() since you are already in the postId node. You can get the data using your "dictionaries" variable. To get the data, do like this.

let caption = dictionaries["caption"] as! String

Answer (score 0):

use snapshot haschild to check

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.hasChild("\(self.yourValueToCompare!)"){
            print("Exists in Database")


        }else{
            print("Does not Exists in Database")
        }
    })
```